# What is transaction check in Yum installation

Tags: centos, yum

What is the "Transaction Test" that will be done during installation using yum?

Please explain with details..

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with layering. Roughly: Yum works on top of rpm, yum creates a transaction and then rpm runs the transaction ... but rpm needs to know that the transaction it got is "good", so it tests it first.